# Cut off subsurf supporting geometry only using quads

Tags: modeling, mesh

I want to put an edge loop on this subsurfed base mesh so it acts as supporting geometry for the teeth so they aren't so round:

[image]

However, as you can imagine, this would create some problems in the other parts of the mesh because they would look too "sharp":

[image]

I've tried moving the unnecessary part of the edge loop to the center of the face, but this makes the subsurf in that area flatter, which I do not want. How do I get rid of the unnecessary parts of the edge loop? I want this mesh to be only quads, so a quad-only solution would be preferred.

Comment: Instead of supporting edge loops you can try to add creases to the teeth edges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do all your quads have to be connected? It might be easier to split the mesh, so you have more control over specific parts.

[image]

Comment: This might make sense because teeth are technically not connected to the skull (which is what I'm making), so face normals making the individual meshes look disconnected might not be a problem. Still, I'd like to see a solution that doesn't resort to splitting the mesh up. If there is no good solution like that, I'll mark your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to keep everything joined, you will need to play around with the topology. Something like this might work for you.

[image]

[image]

If you look up Quad topology there are lots of guides that might give you some other ideas.

Comment: is not exactly what he is asking tho...

Answer (score 0):

As surf-sub modelling "expert" ("" because i might not yet become that LOL...)
i tried to recreate your model, so this is what i got, you only need to dissolve part of the edge loop, and the re route the edge like this...
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This creates a problem, however. The Ngons resulting from this create undesirable artifacts in the subsurf.

Comment: in my recreated mesh looks fine, it depends on how you handle the edges there,also you can add other edge to try yo get rid of that make it follow the edge flow...

Comment: It may look fine on your mesh, but my mesh has completely different topology. Simply put, I do not want Ngons in my mesh.

Comment: wanna send me the model tho?

Comment: I have already marked the solution. My problem has already been resolved, so there is no need to do that. Have a nice day.